# How can I focus the document and "unselect" everything in Sublime Text?

Tags: macos, mac, sublime-text-2

Can someone tell me if there is a better way to deselect than using the ESCAPE key? I'm Using OS X.

I often get frustrated when using sublime text if the focus is in the search box at the bottom and I try and do undo / redo because it does undo / redo in the search box and not in document :(

[image]

Then if I press escape to close the find box and press "Command+G" to go to the next match, but I have text selected that was previously found in the document, it tries to find the next match inside the selection.

This is just a little frustrating and I wish there was an easier way to find the next selection of something "in the whole document" and have the undo / redo keys work in the document context and not in the search box context.